# gulp and global variables set inside a function by DOM selector

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, gulp, var

Still learning javascript for some weeks, I'm trying to understand about global scoped variables, and how to define them inside of a function to use them globally.

First, here's my gulfile sample:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  pug = require('gulp-pug'),
  puglint = require('gulp-pug-lint'),
  dom = require('gulp-dom'),
  projectName,  // Trying to declare a yet undefined global variable (don't know if its the right way)
  PATH = {
    HTML: {
      NAME: projectName + '.html', // This PATH won't be used before the variable value will be set
      SRC: 'dev/main.pug',
      DEST: 'dist/'
    }
  };

// Compile html from pug and set the html title to a global variable
gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src(PATH.HTML.SRC)
    .pipe(puglint())
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(dom(function() {
      projectName = this.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML; // Trying to set the variable's value at a global scope, but doesn't work...
      return this;
    } ))
    .pipe(rename(PATH.HTML.NAME))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.HTML.DEST));
} );
```

So, what i'm trying to do is to get the "title" innerHTML of my processed file, and assign it to a global variable to make it usable inside other functions.
But all it returns is "undefined".
Thinking that it's probably because of a processing ordering problem, I so tried to change my rename pipe to this:

```
...
.pipe(rename(projectName + '.html'))
...
```

But even then it still returns `undefined` (so then outputs a file called "undefined.html").

I don't know if the problem comes from the variable itself or maybe it's my call for `getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML` that is not set correctly and returns `undefined`.

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is you run your `dom` function on a `pug` file. 
`gulp dom` function should run on a `HTML` file.

Before you convert your `.pug` file into a `HTML` file, piped the `dom` function.

Add another `gulp` task to execute the `dom` function after the `pug` file conversion. This way you won't get the `undefined` value.

An example implementation should like below.

```
gulp.task('dom', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe(dom(function(){
            return this.querySelectorAll('body')[0].setAttribute('data-version', '1.0');
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});
```

Read more about the `dom` function here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dom

Comment: Ok ! I thought that by passing the `dom` function after the `pug` pipe, the stream should already look like "real" html markup file. Another way to solve my problem would also to extract the title directly from the .pug file. I'm gonna figure out and make some searches. Otherwise I would probably have to create a new task (like you advise me to do) and add the pug task as a dependency. Thank you for your answer !